# All process handles are the same (CreateToolhelp32Snapshot)

Tags: c++

For some reason all window handles I retrieve are the same..

[image: handles]

I don't see why this is the case.

```
int classname::functionname(const char* processname)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, processname) == 0)
            {  
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION + PROCESS_VM_READ + PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                cout << "Name: " << processname << " Handle: " << hProcess << endl;
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no reason why the system would not re-use process handles.  Have you tried commenting out the `CloseHandle(hProcess);` bit temporarily, forcing the system not to re-use the handles, to see if the process handles are different?

#### Edit

That does it for me.  Play with the following program.  Just edit the value of `REUSE_PROCESS_HANDLE` to see the effect.

```
#undef UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define REUSE_PROCESS_HANDLE 0

int main ()
{
    const char processname[] = "chrome.exe";
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, processname) == 0)
            {  
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION + PROCESS_VM_READ + PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                cout << "Name: " << processname << " Handle: " << hProcess << endl;
#if REUSE_PROCESS_HANDLE
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
#endif
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);
}
```

Comment: Well that's weird.. that did the trick. Thought I don't understand why. It both opens and closes the handle in the while so what's going on? And where should I put CloseHandle now?

Comment: @natli: don't remove it.  It's exactly where it should be.  Removing the `CloseHandle()` would be a resource leak.

Comment: @natli: The process handle is just a *local* identifier.  The same code in another process might yield different handle values for the same process.  Your code always prints the same handle because the system re-uses the identifier after you've called `CloseHandle()`.  This is perfectly normal and there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: I need a unique handle, becausing I'm using them to call TerminateProcess. How can I realise this if I can't remove CloseHandle due to resource leaking?

Comment: If you close the handle, you can't use it for TerminateProcess anyway. So you have to keep it around for later. If you don't close handles, the system won't use the same identifier for a new handle because it's already in use.

Comment: @pezcode Ah, sorry, I get it now. I'll just have to call CloseHandle for each specific process when I'm done with them.